# Implementing a PDO in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I've been adapting old PHP code, because it had no security whatsoever. Admittedly, I'm inexperienced when it comes PDO syntax. So I likely need to alter some of the later statements. I was able to hash and salt passwords and able get the password verify function to work. I then began to incorporate a prepared statement, but ran into difficulties. The ISSET function correctly identifies missing fields. However, when I execute the statement I get a blank page. So have no error messages to go by. Even when I hardcode the admin username into the SQL statement, the password does not get checked by the password_verify function. Nor is any session role being assigned. So even when you get to the admin page. You'll be told you don't have the right user privileges to access it.

```
<?php
// start session
 session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>


<?php
// Import the credentials
include 'dbinfo.php';

try  
{  
    
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);  
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
    {  
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
        {  
        echo "all fields required";  
        }  
           else  
           {  
                $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
                $statement->execute();
                $row = $statement->fetch();  
                
                (  
                     array
                     (  
                        'username' => $_POST["username"]  
                      //'password' => $_POST["password"]  
                     )  
                ); 


                if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $password))
                {
                echo "valid";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "not valid";
                }
                
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                    $role = $row['role'];
    
                    //set session variable
                    $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
    
     
                    //  echo "Successful login!";
                    //redirect
                    header("Location: AdminEdit.html");
    
                }
                else
                {
                echo "Record not found <br />";
                echo "<a href='Admin.html'>Back to login page</a>";
                }
            }  
    }  
}

catch(PDOException $error)  
{  
    $message = $error->getMessage();  
}






?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your PHP code really inside of HTML?

Comment: Remove that `try-catch` from your code. It is a bad practice and you don't need it at all

Comment: ` $statement->execute();` needs to have an array as an argument. You didn't provide anything.

Comment: `$count = $statement->rowCount(); if($count > 0)` is completely useless and redundant. Remove it.

Comment: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` is not needed and obviously a left over from your old project.

Comment: Also [check this out](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) to go with the adaptation. Has very helpful PDO information.

Comment: Better yet, [directly to the actual example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash) that just shows the code without much fuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters that you're binding to your query into your `execute` statement returned from the `prepare` method.

You should also check to see that the username / password is not empty. This can be done using `array_diff` on the `array_keys` rather than manually line by line checking or looping.

```
if(array_diff(['username', 'password'], array_keys($_POST)))
{
    # TODO: Create this exception to trigger a HTML response view
    throw SomeRequiredArgException;
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);

# fetch the record the usual way
$record = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
# check whether a record exists and password is correct in one go
if($record && password_verify($_POST['password'], $record->password)) {
    # Successful login attempt
    # TODO: Set your session correctly as stated at the bottom of this answer.
} else {
    # TODO: send back a wrong credentials message to a user;
}
```

**Future point to note:** I would not set the session value that elevates access to your application as something like a role. I would use a bearer [(JWT)](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt). Failing that, I would create an IV like so.

```
# IV
bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
```

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to figure out how to adapt a declared session to a PDO.

Comment: Right now this code makes no sense as a username is not an array. I'll simplify it for you

Comment: Also, wrong credentials is not an exceptional situation but rather expected behavior.

Comment: Then when `fetch` returns empty and OP attempts to run `password_verify` on the `$record->password` and gets an exception/warning that the property `password` doesn't exist, what then? Also, incorrect credentials doesn't follow rule within this context thus can be treated as an exception so what is your weird issue here? @YourCommonSense

Comment: With your old code there was never a password property. With the new code, there is never a property doesn't exist notice/warning

Comment: `$record->password` [will throw a warning](https://3v4l.org/FfVpp) if the `execute` function returns an empty object. Fact. Therefore, my `isset()` method ensured that before we made a call to use the `$record` instance, it existed first. The same as `$stmt->rowCount() > 0` would do. @YourCommonSense

Comment: With the present condition it will not. Boolean logic.

Comment: Yes, with your present logic using `if($record)` will work also. But your callout of my code making no sense is incorrect, it works fine and above you have an explanation for it: browsing SO at 1am usually leads to missing the basic `if($record)` and leading to "long-line-ism"... if that offended you, I'm sorry but nothing is incorrect about it especially enough to kick a fuss over @YourCommonSense

Comment: Your old code was an unnecessary complicated way to assign a username to a $record variable, `$record = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))->username`. Holding a scalar username value, $record would have never contain a password property.

Comment: We are not checking if the password property exists, you could of checked any property the SQL query selects, it wouldn't change anything because the goal was to ensure that the record was not empty, nothing more or nothing less. So it does make sense, and it does work. Thanks for your addition in scaling it down, like I said, 1am usually leads to long-line-ism (Y) but undermining the solution? There was no need for that, it worked and any additions would of been a nice to have without the unnecessary attempt to belittle as we are all here to learn @YourCommonSense